# Multi fragments when i change rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have three fragment:

- Fragment1 Home
- Fragment2 Search
- Fragment3 Details

and I want to see "home" on the right side of the fragment and when I click on the button in the "home" fragment I want "details" to appear on the left of the fragment.

As in this figure

[image]

I've searched and read a few posts on this site and at other sites, but I did not find an example to help me figure out how I can do it.

can you give me an example or  a link where it is explained ? please

Comment: refer https://github.com/codepath/android-master-detail-demo